# Is Aldrich Killian stronger than Thor?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, the-avengers-2012, iron-man-3

In *Avengers*, Thor vs Iron Man fight scene:

Both had a good fight, but still Thor wasn't able to break Iron Man's suit. Even throwing his Mjlonir hammer at it had no effect. But on the other hand, look at the Iron Man vs Aldrich Killian fight in *Iron Man 3*. Aldrich destroys almost five to six armour suits of Tony's just by his hands? Does this make him stronger than Thor's hammer?

Comment: Was Thor trying to murder Tony? I interpreted that in their fight Thor was holding back to try and disable or incapacitate Iron Man, rather than kill him. Killian, on the other hand was definitely intent on grievously injuring Tony Stark.

Comment: Why should Thor go about killing people

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is the Mandarin stronger than Thor? No-but his body has a different composition, becoming super hot while fighting/angered. He's able to destroy the Iron Man suits because he's essentially a walking laser. Thor-who was using blunt force against armor, and even started to destroy the suit when he and Tony were locked up. The super hot body of Aldrich is not giving him strength above Thor, just a different means of causing damage-thru the heat being generated.

Comment: Been a while since I've seen the movie so correct me if I'm wrong, but IIRC the Mandarin =/= Aldrich Killian. The first sentence should be "is an Extremis-infected individual stronger than Thor?". EDIT: I'm only talking about the movie.

Comment: Killian identifies himself as the "real" Mandarin: *"You said you wanted the Mandarin. You're looking right at him.It was always me, Tony. Right from the start."* The issue is that *All Hail The King* reveals that Killian is also not the real Mandarin.